# Find and replace and get count of replaced content values

Tags: regex, perl

I need to find and replace the content using regex known or unknown pattern, and then we need to store finding content, replaced content, count of replaced content: (I need to do get this from more 100 replacements)

> Here we need to get

**1)Find content

2)Replaced content and

3)count values**:

> Example: <find> <replace> --> Count

In addition we couldn't assume this and that might be whatever we are finding and replacing we should get this report.

I tried my best:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'Trp $\mathbf{R}^a$ locates \alpha \beta distantly $\mathrm{R}^a$ from $\mathit{R}^a$ cys25 in both \gamma and cathepsin K, with \alpha high and moderate $\mathbb{R}^1H$ strengths, respectively. The protein $\mathds{R}^a$ modification $\mathds{R}^1H$ largely \beta affects the binding sites and stability \gamma of the \gamma peptides, and the effects depend on \alpha the elemental compositions of the peptides';

#Sample :
$str=~s{<findcontent>}{<replacedcontent>}g;


#Tried something *different*
my $cnt=0; my (@pushStatsreport,$Statsreport) = "";

$str=~s/\\alpha/my $find=$&; my $rep = "\\boldsymbol\{\\alpha\}"; $cnt++; $Statsreport = "Find: $find\tRep: $rep\tCnt: $cnt\n"; ($rep); /ge;
push(@pushStatsreport, $Statsreport); $cnt=0;

$str=~s/\\math(it|rm|bf)\s*([a-z])\b/my $find = $&; my $rep = "\\checkmath$1\{$2\}"; $cnt++; $Statsreport = "Find: $find\tRep: $rep\tCnt: $cnt\n"; ($rep); /ge;
push(@pushStatsreport, $Statsreport);

print join "\n", @pushStatsreport;
```

my result and desired output:

> Find: \alpha    Rep: \boldsymbol{\alpha}        Cnt: 3
>   Find: \mathbf a Rep: \checkmathbf{a}      Cnt: 2

However I couldn't accept this is the better way. Someone could help me on this.

Comment: Please consider formatting your code using something like `perltidy`; it is really difficult to understand with several statements on the same line, and lines like `$str=~s{<findcontent>}{<replacedcontent>}g;` -- what does this mean? Are `<findcontent>` and `<replacedcontent>` real strings? A clearer question will make it easier for people to answer.

Comment: The input string `$str` contains just one instance of `\mathbf{R}`, how is this consistent with the desired output of `\mathbf a`? Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

You could try to put the search and replace strings into an array of arrays, and then iterate to do the substitutions and collect the counts and reports:

```
my @findreplace = (
    [ q<\\\\alpha>, q<\boldsymbol{\alpha}>],
    [ q<\\\\math(it|rm|bf)\s*([a-z])\b>, q<\checkmath$1{$2}>],
);

my (@pushStatsreport, $Statsreport);
for my $item (@findreplace) {
    my ( $regex, $replace ) = @$item;
    my $cnt = $str =~ s{$regex}{'"$replace"'}eeg;
    $Statsreport = "Find: $regex\tRep: $replace\tCnt: $cnt";
    push @pushStatsreport, $Statsreport;
}
```